# Extract object/array value from rest API output using unix and jq

Tags: json, rest, unix, curl, jq

When I run below curl query which makes call to REST API, it gives me two record in terms of issues. I would like to get "key" (SEA-739), "status" (Open) and "assignee" (null or emailAddress). Also how can i get count of no. of issues retrieved via "expand": operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",

I tried curl | jq '.issues[0].id' and it gives me valid id but I couldn't loop through both issues and get mentioned 3 values for both? How can I count issue using shell and get required output for all issues one by one?

JSON output from jq:

```
root@server# curl -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --insecure --silent 'https://myserver.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=SE&status=Closed%20order%20by%20key%20desc&maxResults=2' | jq

{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 2,
  "total": 733,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "292697",
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issue/292697",
      "key": "SEA-739",
      "fields": {
    "customfield_10190": null,
    "customfield_13580": null,
    "customfield_10192": null,
    "customfield_10072": null,
    "customfield_13582": null,
    "customfield_10194": null,
    "customfield_13581": [],
    "customfield_10074": null,
    "customfield_13980": [
      {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/15071",
        "value": "check user base",
        "id": "15071"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_10075": null,
    "customfield_11680": null,
    "customfield_13583": null,
    "customfield_10076": null,
    "customfield_10230": null,
    "fixVersions": [],
    "customfield_10231": null,
    "customfield_13189": null,
    "customfield_13981": null,
    "customfield_10232": null,
    "resolution": null,
    "customfield_10233": null,
    "customfield_10234": null,
    "customfield_14380": null,
    "lastViewed": null,
    "customfield_10580": null,
    "customfield_12880": null,
    "customfield_10581": null,
    "customfield_12882": null,
    "customfield_10220": null,
    "customfield_12881": null,
    "priority": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/priority/4",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/images/icons/priorities/minor.svg",
      "name": "P4",
      "id": "4"
    },
    "customfield_10221": null,
    "customfield_10980": null,
    "customfield_10101": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10377",
      "value": "NO",
      "id": "10377"
    },
    "customfield_10222": null,
    "customfield_12883": "0|i16rjz:",
    "labels": [],
    "customfield_13208": null,
    "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
    "timeestimate": null,
    "versions": [],
    "issuelinks": [],
    "assignee": null,
    "status": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/status/1",
      "description": "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it.",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/images/icons/statuses/open.png",
      "name": "Open",
      "id": "1",
      "statusCategory": {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
        "id": 2,
        "key": "new",
        "colorName": "blue-gray",
        "name": "To Do"
      }
    },
    "components": [],
    "customfield_13281": null,
    "customfield_13280": null,
    "customfield_13283": null,
    "customfield_13282": null,
    "customfield_13680": null,
    "customfield_11780": "9223372036854775807",
    "customfield_11782": null,
    "customfield_13201": null,
    "customfield_11781": null,
    "customfield_10210": null,
    "customfield_13203": null,
    "customfield_13202": null,
    "customfield_13204": null,
    "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
    "customfield_14480": "com.atlassian.servicedesk.plugins.approvals.internal.customfield.ApprovalsCFValue@7735d8eb",
    "creator": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/user?username=user1",
      "name": "user1",
      "key": "user1",
      "emailAddress": "user1@mycompany.com",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10312",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10312",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10312",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10312"
      },
      "displayName": "User1",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "customfield_10280": null,
    "subtasks": [],
    "customfield_10160": "org.hakanai.jira.plugins.StatusColor@50",
    "customfield_12580": null,
    "reporter": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/user?username=user1",
      "name": "user1",
      "key": "user1",
      "emailAddress": "user1@mycompany.com",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10312",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10312",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10312",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10312"
      },
      "displayName": "User1",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "customfield_12980": null,
    "aggregateprogress": {
      "progress": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "customfield_10200": null,
    "progress": {
      "progress": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "customfield_14080": null,
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/25",
      "id": "25",
      "description": "test account checking",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/download/resources/com.thed.zephyr.je/images/icons/ico_zephyr_issuetype.png",
      "name": "Test",
      "subtask": false
    },
    "customfield_11080": null,
    "customfield_14191": null,
    "customfield_11081": null,
    "customfield_11082": null,
    "customfield_11083": null,
    "customfield_10270": null,
    "customfield_11084": null,
    "customfield_13780": null,
    "timespent": null,
    "customfield_10150": 99999,
    "customfield_11480": null,
    "customfield_13782": null,
    "customfield_10152": null,
    "customfield_13781": null,
    "project": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/project/10162",
      "id": "10162",
      "key": "SEA",
      "name": "Test Automation",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10162&avatarId=10032"
      },
      "projectCategory": {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10020",
        "id": "10020",
        "description": "All IT related tasks and projects",
        "name": "Corporate IT"
      }
    },
    "customfield_11880": null,
    "aggregatetimespent": null,
    "resolutiondate": null,
    "workratio": -1,
    "customfield_14190": null,
    "customfield_14182": null,
    "customfield_14183": null,
    "watches": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issue/SEA-739/watchers",
      "watchCount": 1,
      "isWatching": false
    },
    "customfield_14181": null,
    "customfield_14186": null,
    "customfield_10380": null,
    "customfield_12680": null,
    "created": "2016-10-29T16:17:57.000-0400",
    "customfield_10260": null,
    "customfield_14185": null,
    "customfield_10140": null,
    "customfield_10261": null,
    "customfield_10020": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10380",
      "value": "S3",
      "id": "10380"
    },
    "customfield_10262": null,
    "customfield_10780": null,
    "updated": "2016-10-29T16:17:57.000-0400",
    "customfield_13081": null,
    "customfield_13080": null,
    "customfield_13083": "To be filled in by Engineering",
    "customfield_11180": null,
    "customfield_13082": null,
    "customfield_11181": null,
    "customfield_13085": null,
    "customfield_11182": null,
    "customfield_13084": null,
    "customfield_11580": null,
    "customfield_11183": null,
    "customfield_13087": null,
    "customfield_13086": null,
    "timeoriginalestimate": null,
    "customfield_13881": null,
    "customfield_10130": null,
    "description": "Please ignore test bug..",
    "customfield_13880": null,
    "customfield_10011": null,
    "customfield_10253": null,
    "customfield_10012": null,
    "customfield_10007": null,
    "customfield_10008": null,
    "customfield_10009": null,
    "summary": "Please ignore test bug..",
    "customfield_13191": null,
    "customfield_13190": null,
    "customfield_14282": null,
    "customfield_13193": null,
    "customfield_13192": null,
    "customfield_14280": null,
    "customfield_13195": null,
    "customfield_14285": [
      {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/15507",
        "value": " YES",
        "id": "15507"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_13194": null,
    "customfield_14283": null,
    "customfield_10480": null,
    "customfield_13196": null,
    "customfield_14284": null,
    "customfield_10085": null,
    "customfield_12780": null,
    "customfield_10120": null,
    "customfield_10241": null,
    "customfield_10088": null,
    "customfield_10121": null,
    "customfield_10000": null,
    "customfield_10242": null,
    "customfield_10880": null,
    "customfield_10089": null,
    "customfield_10122": null,
    "customfield_10243": null,
    "customfield_10002": null,
    "customfield_10244": null,
    "customfield_10486": null,
    "customfield_10124": null,
    "customfield_10003": null,
    "customfield_10245": null,
    "customfield_10487": null,
    "customfield_10488": null,
    "customfield_10236": null,
    "customfield_10237": null,
    "environment": null,
    "duedate": null
      }
    },

    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "273625",
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issue/273625",
      "key": "SEA-738",
      "fields": {
    "customfield_10190": null,
    "customfield_13580": null,
    "customfield_10192": null,
    "customfield_10072": null,
    "customfield_10193": null,
    "customfield_13582": null,
    "customfield_10194": null,
    "customfield_13581": [],
    "customfield_10074": null,
    "customfield_13980": null,
    "customfield_10075": null,
    "customfield_11680": null,
    "customfield_13583": null,
    "customfield_10076": null,
    "customfield_10230": null,
    "fixVersions": [],
    "customfield_10231": null,
    "customfield_13189": null,
    "customfield_13981": null,
    "customfield_10232": null,
    "customfield_11685": null,
    "resolution": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/resolution/1",
      "id": "1",
      "description": "A fix for this issue is checked into the tree and tested.",
      "name": "Fixed"
    },
    "customfield_10233": null,
    "customfield_10234": null,
    "customfield_14380": null,
    "lastViewed": null,
    "customfield_10580": null,
    "customfield_12880": null,
    "customfield_10581": null,
    "customfield_12882": null,
    "customfield_10220": null,
    "customfield_12881": null,
    "priority": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/priority/3",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/images/icons/priorities/major.svg",
      "name": "P3",
      "id": "3"
    },
    "customfield_10221": null,
    "customfield_10980": null,
    "customfield_10101": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10377",
      "value": "NO",
      "id": "10377"
    },
    "customfield_10222": null,
    "customfield_12883": "0|i13y67:",
    "labels": [],
    "customfield_13208": null,
    "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
    "timeestimate": null,
    "versions": [],
    "issuelinks": [],
    "assignee": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/user?username=user2",
      "name": "user2",
      "key": "user2",
      "emailAddress": "user2@mycompany.com",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10312",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10312",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10312",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10312"
      },
      "displayName": "Russell Pratt",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "EST5EDT"
    },
    "status": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/status/5",
      "description": "A resolution has been taken and is awaiting verification by reporter. From here issues are either reopened or are closed.",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/images/icons/statuses/resolved.png",
      "name": "Resolved",
      "id": "5",
      "statusCategory": {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
        "id": 3,
        "key": "done",
        "colorName": "green",
        "name": "Done"
      }
    },
    "components": [],
    "customfield_13281": null,
    "customfield_13280": null,
    "customfield_13283": null,
    "customfield_13282": null,
    "customfield_13680": null,
    "customfield_11780": "9223372036854775807",
    "customfield_11782": null,
    "customfield_13201": null,
    "customfield_11781": null,
    "customfield_10210": null,
    "customfield_13203": null,
    "customfield_13202": null,
    "customfield_13204": null,
    "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
    "customfield_14480": "com.atlassian.servicedesk.plugins.approvals.internal.customfield.ApprovalsCFValue@c4b41a5",
    "creator": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/user?username=userads",
      "name": "userads",
      "key": "userads",
      "emailAddress": "userads@mycompany.com",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412"
      },
      "displayName": "User Ads",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "EST5EDT"
    },
    "customfield_10280": null,
    "subtasks": [],
    "customfield_10160": "org.hakanai.jira.plugins.StatusColor@54",
    "customfield_12580": null,
    "reporter": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/user?username=userads",
      "name": "userads",
      "key": "userads",
      "emailAddress": "userads@mycompany.com",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=userads&avatarId=15412"
      },
      "displayName": "User Ads",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "EST5EDT"
    },
    "customfield_12980": null,
    "aggregateprogress": {
      "progress": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "customfield_10200": null,
    "progress": {
      "progress": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "customfield_14080": null,
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
      "id": "3",
      "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
      "iconUrl": "https://testserver.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=14808&avatarType=issuetype",
      "name": "Task",
      "subtask": false,
      "avatarId": 14808
    },
    "customfield_11080": null,
    "customfield_14191": null,
    "customfield_11081": null,
    "customfield_11082": null,
    "customfield_11083": null,
    "customfield_10270": null,
    "customfield_11084": null,
    "customfield_13780": null,
    "timespent": null,
    "customfield_10150": null,
    "customfield_11480": null,
    "customfield_13782": null,
    "customfield_10152": null,
    "customfield_13781": null,
    "project": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/project/10162",
      "id": "10162",
      "key": "SEA",
      "name": "Test Automation",
      "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "24x24": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "16x16": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10162&avatarId=10032",
        "32x32": "https://testserver.com/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10162&avatarId=10032"
      },
      "projectCategory": {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10020",
        "id": "10020",
        "description": "All IT related tasks and projects",
        "name": "Corporate IT"
      }
    },
    "customfield_11880": null,
    "aggregatetimespent": null,
    "resolutiondate": "2016-04-21T09:59:34.000-0400",
    "workratio": -1,
    "customfield_14190": null,
    "customfield_14182": null,
    "customfield_14183": null,
    "watches": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/issue/SEA-738/watchers",
      "watchCount": 2,
      "isWatching": false
    },
    "customfield_14181": null,
    "customfield_14186": null,
    "customfield_10380": null,
    "customfield_12680": null,
    "created": "2016-04-07T13:11:56.000-0400",
    "customfield_10260": null,
    "customfield_14185": null,
    "customfield_10140": null,
    "customfield_10261": null,
    "customfield_10020": {
      "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10380",
      "value": "S3",
      "id": "10380"
    },
    "customfield_10262": null,
    "customfield_10780": null,
    "updated": "2016-04-21T10:27:28.000-0400",
    "customfield_13081": null,
    "customfield_13080": null,
    "customfield_13083": "To be filled in by Engineering",
    "customfield_11180": null,
    "customfield_13082": null,
    "customfield_11181": null,
    "customfield_13085": null,
    "customfield_11182": null,
    "customfield_13084": null,
    "customfield_11580": null,
    "customfield_11183": null,
    "customfield_13087": null,
    "customfield_13086": null,
    "timeoriginalestimate": null,
    "customfield_13881": null,
    "customfield_10130": null,
    "description": "We need to update CTL logins for Cuke and RC.Currently the way the automation is setup, we can only use one user per environment, so please pick one from below for UAT and a different one for Prod.\r\n\r\n1. uat_centurylinknet:\r\n  :username: syntest6@centurylink.net\r\n  :password: P@ssw0rd!\r\n2. uat_embarqmailcom:\r\n  :username: synqe12@embarqmail.com\r\n  :password: P@ssw0rd!\r\n3. uat_qcom:\r\n  :username: syn_test_prism@q.com\r\n  :password: P@ssw0rd!\r\n4. prod_centurylinknet:\r\n  :username: syn_test_res03@centurylink.net\r\n  :password: test03\r\n5. prod_embarqmailcom:\r\n  :username: syn_test_res25@embarqmail.com\r\n  :password: test25\r\n6. prod_qcom:\r\n  :username: syn_test_prism@q.com\r\n  :password: test01",
    "customfield_13880": null,
    "customfield_11980": null,
    "customfield_10011": null,
    "customfield_10253": null,
    "customfield_10012": null,
    "customfield_10007": null,
    "customfield_10008": null,
    "customfield_10009": null,
    "summary": "Update CTL Logins",
    "customfield_13191": null,
    "customfield_13190": null,
    "customfield_14282": null,
    "customfield_13193": null,
    "customfield_13192": null,
    "customfield_14280": null,
    "customfield_13195": null,
    "customfield_14285": null,
    "customfield_13194": null,
    "customfield_14283": null,
    "customfield_10084": null,
    "customfield_10480": null,
    "customfield_13196": null,
    "customfield_14284": null,
    "customfield_10085": null,
    "customfield_12780": null,
    "customfield_10120": null,
    "customfield_10241": null,
    "customfield_10088": null,
    "customfield_10121": null,
    "customfield_10000": [
      {
        "self": "https://testserver.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10009",
        "value": "CenturyLink",
        "id": "10009"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_10242": null,
    "customfield_10880": null,
    "customfield_10089": null,
    "customfield_10122": null,
    "customfield_10243": null,
    "customfield_10002": null,
    "customfield_10244": null,
    "customfield_10486": null,
    "customfield_10124": null,
    "customfield_10003": null,
    "customfield_10245": null,
    "customfield_10487": null,
    "customfield_10488": null,
    "customfield_10236": null,
    "customfield_10237": null,
    "environment": null,
    "duedate": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any details about the expected form of the output, but the following jq filter produces the information you seem to want (but some of your requirements are not too clear to me):

```
(.issues[] | {key, status: .fields.status.name, assignee: .fields.assignee.emailAddress}),
(.issues|length)
```

Output:

```
 {  
  "key": "SEA-739",
  "status": "Open",
  "assignee": null
}
{
  "key": "SEA-738",
  "status": "Resolved",
  "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com"
}
2
```

#### Postscript

If you want a one-liner that will produce the values as a stream, without quotation marks, consider:

```
$ jq -r '.issues | ((.[] | (.key, .fields.status.name, .fields.assignee.emailAddress)),length)'
```

Output:

```
SEA-739
Open
null
SEA-738
Resolved
user2@mycompany.com
2
```

Comment: Maybe you aligned `status` and `assignee` on the same level as `expand`, which it is - inside `issues[].fields`, but those two fields don't exist directly under `issues[]`, (but `expand` does`)

Comment: @hmedia1 - The answer has been tweaked accordingly.

Comment: This is really what i needed and I'm very near to accept this as an answer. As mentioned, now i need to key, status and assignee one by one.

Comment: @peak, one more time I need your help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396445/get-customized-output-from-rest-api-output-using-jq-linux

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get "key" (SEA-739), "status" (Open) and "assignee"
>   (null or emailAddress).
>
> ....
>   count of no. of issues retrieved via "expand": operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",

This:

- ```
  jq '.issues[] | { key, status:.fields.status.name, assignee: .fields.assignee.emailAddress, "total issues":{expand,count:( .expand | split(",") | length ) } }'
  ```

Will result;

- ```
  {
    "key": "SEA-739",
    "status": "Open",
    "assignee": null,
    "total issues": {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "count": 5
    }
  }
  {
    "key": "SEA-738",
    "status": "Resolved",
    "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com",
    "total issues": {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "count": 5
    }
  }
  ```

If that's what you're after.  It's not entirely clear as you have some non-unique keys being used in different places, and you're explicit requirements to count the expand properties don't really make a lot of sense to me, but your requirements seemed well explained.

Comment: one more time need your help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396445/get-customized-output-from-rest-api-output-using-jq-linux