# Get outputs from jq on a single line

Tags: json, jq

I got below output using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330344

```
 (.issues[] | {key, status: .fields.status.name, assignee: .fields.assignee.emailAddress})
```

Output:

```
 {  
   "key": "SEA-739",
   "status": "Open",
   "assignee": null
 }
 {
   "key": "SEA-738",
   "status": "Resolved",
   "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com"
 }
```

But I need to parse each and every line but it's tough to identify which assignee is for which key as far as key group is concerned. Is this possible to make one bunch in one row using jq?

Expected output:

```
{ "key": "SEA-739", "status": "Open", "assignee": null }
{ "key": "SEA-738", "status": "Resolved", "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com"}
```

OR

```
{ "SEA-739", "Open", null }
{ "SEA-738", "Resolved", user2@mycompany.com }
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**`-c`** is what you likely need

Using the output you posted above, you can process it further:

```
jq -c . input
```

To Give;

```
{"key":"SEA-739","status":"Open","assignee":null}
{"key":"SEA-738","status":"Resolved","assignee":"user2@mycompany.com"}
```

Or you can just change your original command

**FROM**

```
jq -r '(.issues[] | {key, status: .fields.status.name, assignee: .fields.assignee.emailAddress})'
```

**TO**

```
jq -c '(.issues[] | {key, status: .fields.status.name, assignee: .fields.assignee.emailAddress})'
```

Comment: Long version of -c is --compact-output

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178636/how-to-use-jq-to-output-jsonl-one-independent-json-object-per-line . It seems that sometimes you have to run the query twice: `$ curl | jq -c '.[]'  | jq -c '.[]' `

Comment: @NeilG That is an array depth issue, not a formatting one.  The example you've given is the same as running `jq -c '.[][]'`

Comment: Consider also cases when `-j` to remove trailing newline helps.

Comment: `-c` creates problem if value has space in it. like `{"randKey":"rand value"}`. in this case `jq` only reads till `{"randKey":"rand` and the rest will be ignored. whats the solution?

Comment: @DragonKnight That’s an external issue, nothing to do with `jq`.  You must be delimiting spaces in your output or similar

Comment: Hmm... I have the same problem with similar input and jq 1.6 always inserts a newline between my fields, whether I have -c or -r. How strange.

Answer (score 43):

Not precisely an answer to the long version of the question, but for people who Googled this looking for other single line output formats from jq:

```
$ jq -r '[.key, .status, .assignee]|@tsv' <<<'
 {
   "key": "SEA-739",
   "status": "Open",
   "assignee": null
 }
 {
   "key": "SEA-738",
   "status": "Resolved",
   "assignee": "user2@mycompany.com"
 }'
```

outputs:

```
SEA-739 Open
SEA-738 Resolved        user2@mycompany.com
```

`@sh` rather than `@tsv` returns:

```
'SEA-739' 'Open' null
'SEA-738' 'Resolved' 'user2@mycompany.com'
```

Additionally, there are other output formats to do things such as escape the output, like `@html`, or encode it, as with `@base64`. The list is available in the *Format strings and escaping* section of either the *jq(1)* man page or online at [stedolan.github.io/jq/manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: The `@tsv` is crucial, without that (or the `@sh`) my output had each value on its own line.  Helpful answer!  I wasn't able to find this "string" version (instead of json format) anywhere else.

Comment: Very helpful! Note that the answer uses `-r` for proper output. Other options are `@csv`, `@text`, `@base64` and options for escaping like `@uri`, `@html`.

The relevant manual section is here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping

Answer (score 2):

The answers with "-c" and "-r" didn't work for me with jq version 1.6. What I did was the following:

Given input like

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "puppetmaster": "",
    "ansible_job_template_id": "117",
    "lifecycle_environment": "Dev",
    "hostname": "childmas01",
}
```

And a jq command like

```
jq -r '.parameters | .hostname,.lifecycle_environment' filename
```

I got output like this:

```
childmas01
Dev
```

I got the same results with -c instead of -r, and also with -cr. So I simply made the results into an array, and joined them with a space, like this:

```
jq -r '.parameters | [ .hostname,.lifecycle_environment ] | join(" ")'  filename
```

To get this:

```
childmas01 Dev
```