# How to use jq to output JSONL (one independent JSON object per line)

Tags: json, jq, jsonlines

My request sounds trivial but I could not find a way to do it. I have as input an array of JSON objects:

```
[
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2
    },
    {
        "foo": 3,
        "bar": 4
    },
    (...)
]
```

and I want as output the JSONL version of the same, aka one object per line, not an array:

```
    { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }
    { "foo": 3, "bar": 4 }
    (...)
```

This is **not** the same as using `--compact-output`, as that would preserve the array and give me:

```
    [ { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }, { "foo": 3, "bar": 4 }, (...) ]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should be a feature: `--line-output`.
Then you can feed the data into all the unix line-based tools.

Answer (score 60):

The answer to the original question is to use the filter `.[]` together with the `-c` command-line option:

```
$ jq -c '.[]'
```

---

If the input file is very large (notably, if it is too large to fit into memory), it may be better to use jq's `--stream` command-line option, or a companion tool.  If the preservation of numerical precision is important, then you may wish to consider `jm`, which is particularly easy to use: invoking `jm` without any parameters suffices.  See the jq Cookbook: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook

Comment: This didn't work with the direct output, but for some reason running it twice did: `$ curl | jq '.[]'  | jq -c '.[]'`

Answer (score 2):

If the input array is too large to fit into memory, you can use jq's so-called "streaming parser".

Here is an illustration using a generic approach, that is, it makes no assumptions about the items in the top-level array:

```
$ echo '[{"foo":"bar"},99,null,{"foo":"baz"}]' |
  jq -cn --stream 'fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[1:]) | select(. != [[]]) )'
{"foo":"bar"}
99
null
{"foo":"baz"}
$
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I captured the response data and then used `cat` to push it through the construct again. In other words, this works: `$ curl | jq -cn --stream 'fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[1:]) | select(. != [[]]) )'  | jq -cn --stream 'fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[1:]) | select(. != [[]]) )'`. Perhaps you could explain what each part of the command does?

Answer (score -2):

Found: it's

```
map(tostring) | reduce .[] as $item (""; . + $item + "\n")
```

You also need to use `--raw-output`.

Comment: This doesn't work either, but at least you can split on `},{`, at least on my data set it worked.