# Split JSON array into an object per line

Tags: javascript, json, ubuntu

Basically, I have a really large JSON file I need to parse, and while searching, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874688/6701776).

The only problem is I don't know how to format my JSON array into a single object per line. Is there a straightforward Javascript/Ubuntu way to do this? (I've used [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) in the past and it's pretty good for minifying json files, for example)

My JSON file looks something like this

```
[
  {
    "country":"monrovia",
    "street" :"grove street",
    "where" : "home"
  },
  {
   "country": "uk", 
   "street": "diagon alley", 
   "where": "mystery"
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]
```

But I need it to look like this

```
[{"country":"monrovia", "street": "grove street", "where": "home"  },
  {"country": "uk", "street": "diagon alley", "where": "mystery happens"},
  {...}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq to the rescue once again! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178760/6701776) is what I needed.

And it's apparently referred to as JSONL.

An even better option is 'new-line delimited JSON' ([ndjson](http://ndjson.org/)). The Javascript implementation of the same (with streams!) is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ld-jsonstream)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is parse the json array by using the JSON.stringify Method like so

```
// This can be the array of json
var obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 29,
    "location": "Denver Colorado",
};
// stringify the json
var result = JSON.stringify(obj);
// see the output
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It places every object in a single line (minifies it). I need them split into different lines per object, instead.

Comment: You can try using this library: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream