# How can I print an arbitrary string with JQ?

Tags: json, string, jq

I'd like to print with JQ arbitrary composed strings.

Suppose I have a json document* as follow:

```js
[{
  "first_name": "Angela",
  "last_name": "Sleney",
  "email": "asleney0@nytimes.com"
}, {
  "first_name": "Clint",
  "last_name": "Ducroe",
  "email": "cducroe1@aboutads.info"
}, {
  "first_name": "Aurthur",
  "last_name": "Tebb",
  "email": "atebb2@fastcompany.com"
}]
```

and with data from above let's say just for example (could be any string) I'd like to print with JQ 3 lines as follow:

```
Email address for user Angela Sleney is "asleney0@nytimes.com"
Email address for user Clint Ducroe is "cducroe1@aboutads.info"
Email address for user Aurthur Tebb is "atebb2@fastcompany.com"
```

How can I do this?

---

Best I was able to do was to print the data 1 per line with:

```
jq -r '.[] | .first_name, .last_name, .email, ""'
```

But result was

```
Angela
Sleney
asleney0@nytimes.com

Clint
Ducroe
cducroe1@aboutads.info

Aurthur
Tebb
atebb2@fastcompany.com
```

*NB: the data comes from random [generator](https://mockaroo.com/), no real names or emails.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396445/get-outputs-from-jq-on-a-single-line

Comment: Not a duplicate but interesting nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried playing around with your json on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/#).

I got the desired result -

```
Email address for user Angela Sleney is "asleney0@nytimes.com"
Email address for user Clint Ducroe is "cducroe1@aboutads.info"
Email address for user Aurthur Tebb is "atebb2@fastcompany.com"
```

with this filter -

```
.[] | "Email address for user \(.first_name) \(.last_name) is \"\(.email)\""
```

Play around with the [`string interpolation \(foo)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) to get your result.

Comment: The way you have the single quotes written isn't necessary, you could use them as is: `'\(.email)'` though double quotes seem to be preferred: `\"\(.email)\"`

Comment: I knew it I was missing a simple feature, I was very surprised that a common request as mine wasn't addressed somehow by the program. RTFM strikes back, totally missed it in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`jq -r '.[] | .first_name + " " + .last_name + " " + .email'`

> Addition: +
>
> The operator + takes two filters:
>
> - Applies them both to the same input
> - Adds the results together.

---

> The term “adding” here has a different meaning depending on the types involved:
>
> - Numbers are added by normal arithmetic.
> - Arrays are added by concatenating each other forming a larger array.
> - Strings are added by appending one with another to form a larger string.
>
> **Refer here for more details:**
>
> Source: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions